# Nested Select SQL statements in an Insert SQL statement

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I'm trying to take values from a Cart(ID PK, Username PK, MenuID) table and an Order(ID PK,Username,Address) table and insert them into an OrderItem(OrderID, MenuID, OrderItemID PK) table.
Its the process of confirming the purchase. So I have to insert all the values from the cart into OrderItem and add the last inserted ID in the Order table

Here's where I'm stuck:

`insert into OrderItem (MenuID, OrderID)  Values (A,B)
A=(Select MenuID from Cart Where Username='Foris')
B=(Select last_insert_rowid() from Order)`

I added the B and A to explain what I meant. I can't do it using using inner joins i think.
Here's an image of the database design
[image: Database]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Removed SQL Server and MySQL because `last_insert_rowid()` is SQLite-specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
insert into OrderItem (MenuID, OrderID)  
    Select MenuID, last_insert_rowid()
    from Cart
    Where Username = 'Foris';
```

I am not sure what `select last_insert_rowid() from Order` is supposed to be.  Well, I do know, that would return all the rows in `Order` with one column, the `last_insert_rowid()` whatever that value might be.

The above assumes that the previous statement was an insert into `Order`.

Comment: it gets the last inserted ID from Order, it won't work that way because the orderID is from the Order table

Comment: @DatForis . . . I've never seen it used that way.  And, I don't see any documentation that suggests that the `from` clause in any way affects the operation of `last_insert_rowid()`.  Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Oh wait I apologize I had the function figured out wrong. The Query you sent works GREAT. Thanks